Can I Conclude $A\not\in F$ from $x\in A$ and $x\not\in\bigcup G$?
Let $x$ be arbitrary.
Given

$x\in\bigcup F$
$x\notin \bigcup G$

Goal

$\exists A \in F\backslash G(x\in A)$

I interpreted the goal as $\exists A (A\in F \land A \notin G \land x \in A)$. Let A stands for a set in $F$ such that $x\in A$. I know now that $A\in F$ and $x\in A$, I only need to prove that $A \notin G$.
I interpreted the 2nd given as $\forall A \in G(x \notin A)$, which I re-expressed as $\forall A (A\in G \implies x \notin A)$ of which the contrapositive is $\forall A (x \in A \implies A\notin G)$. So I concluded $A\notin G$ by modus ponens.
Here's the real kicker. I saw a counterexample online that we cannot conclude $x\notin\bigcup G$ from $x \in A$ and $A\notin G$ and vice versa:
Say that $x=1$, $A=\{1\}$, and $G=\{\{1,2\}\}$. Now both $x\in A$ and $A\notin G$ is true, but $x\notin \bigcap G$ is false.
There must be something wrong with my interpretation or understanding. Please help, this is hurting my brain and my heart.

Your proof is correct. I think you should take some time to think about what the counter example is disproving and try to compare what is disproved to what you have shown. I think you will see that it is not a counter example to what you have shown.
